# How can a before-request function be registered on a third-party Flask Blueprint, at the time of Blueprint registration?

Tags: python, flask

I intend to use a Flask Blueprint provided by a library, and want to register a custom before-request function across all routes of the Blueprint without modifying the code of the Blueprint - i.e. *outside* of the Blueprint and just before or after registering the Blueprint on my app.

Is this possible?

(I note that `Blueprint.before_request()` is meant to be defined along with the Blueprint.)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution/hack:

```
app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)
app.before_request_funcs['my_blueprint'].append(my_before_request_fn)
```

Proviso: [the docs appear to recommend against this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_request_funcs).